# opening and closing modal in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm simulating a chat with ionic2 and I want to open a modal (the chat page), be able to close it and reopen the same modal (with the previous messages that there were before closing the modal).

This is what I've done (I removed boilerplate code):

**homepage.html**

```
<ion-col><ion-icon name="chatbubbles" (click)="presentChatModal()"></ion-icon></ion-col>
```

When I click that icon (in homepage.html) which should open my modal I call this method inside **homepage.ts**

```
presentChatModal() {
        this.chatModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage, {param: this.chats});
        this.ModalPage.onDidDismiss(data => {
             console.log("messages: "+data);
        });
        this.chatModal.present();
    }
```

**modal.html**

```
<button (click)="dismiss()">CLOSE</button>
```

**modal.ts**

```
    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, private viewCtrl: ViewController) {

    this.chats = navParams.get('param');
}

dismiss() {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.chats);
    }
```

This is my problem: I can open the modal, write messages and close the modal; but if I open a modal, close it, re-open it and close it again, when I open the modal for the third time I see the same message 3 times. I guess it is because I create a new modal everytime I try to open it with `presentChatModal`.

Is it possible to destroy a modal so that everytime I call `presentChatModal` I'm sure that other `MyModalPage` objects don't exist?
If not, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: What if you put the first line of presentChatModal outside the function?

Comment: Can you add the code where you add messages to chat ? I don't really understand the issue without it.

Comment: @Lucio  If I try to put this.chatModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage, {param: this.chats}); inside the constructor (I already tried it) I receive this error:  Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges when I try to open after one closing

Comment: Hi, did u find any solution to this?